# Is there a way to convert a multi dimensional array from a json file into an array in visual basic?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a json file containing a multidimensional array called charactervalues.json

```json
[{"Name":"Diluc",
  "BaseATK":335,
  "BaseDef":784,
  "BaseHP":12981,
  "AsStat":"cd",
   AsVal: 24.2 }, 
 {"Name":"Amber",
  "BaseATK":223,
  "BaseDef":601,
  "BaseHP":9461,
  "AsStat":"atk%",
   AsVal: 24 },
 {"Name":"Barbara",
  "BaseATK":159,
  "BaseDef":669,
  "BaseHP":9787,
  "AsStat":"hp%",
   AsVal: 24 },
 {"Name":"Beidou",
  "BaseATK":225,
  "BaseDef":648,
  "BaseHP":13050,
  "AsStat":"electro%",
   AsVal: 24 }]
```

Is there any way to use this array as an array in visual basic? I've tried json.net but haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: json.net is DotNet - are you sure you are talking about VBA? Do you mean VB.Net?

Comment: Are you sure that's a **multi**dimensional array?  It looks like a 1d array of objects to me.  Is there some additional content in the file corresponding to the `...` characters?

Comment: As shown here, that's a simple array of objects, so it can be deserialized as a `List(Of Class)`. Build a class object with properties that describe the object's members.